# Get specific value from text and insert in array, then compare on it

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to make a script in order to extract some data and then launch a command.
Here is the deal:
I have an application that sometimes goes in error (I have to look in the log file) with a specific error code (always the same) and in the same line I have an "ID", the IDT.

So my problem is:
I have to take a look in this log file every 5 minutes and search for the error code **CFTT82E** and in this line to get the value of my IDT that is numeric, here what looks like the line:

`14/01/15 12:20:06  CFTT82E transfer aborted  IDTU=A0009L7Q PART=DGISSL IDF=LKEMDDIB IDT=A1512489 730 ABO 215>`

Once I got the value in a variable, I have to wait 5 more minutes and then to launch a command by using the value of my IDT, that is to say:

`cmd -toto $IDT_value`

Now, once the command succeeded (I have to compare only with **CFTR12I** code AND my IDT value), I will have a message like that:

`14/01/15 15:48:39  CFTR12I END Treated for USER Système PART=DGISSL IDF=* IDT=A1512489>`

At this moment, I'll exit, else, I'll relaunch the same command.

But, as this script should work in Loop every 5 minutes, the next time that I'll parse the log file, I should ignore the IDT that I already used before.
I thought to make an array with the daily IDT values (at the end of the date we could empty the array or the variable or whatever this object will be) and then compare the values at every loop.

I already started with this but as I'm newbie,I think that I didn't make a good start :

```
clear
Get-Content C:\CFT\LOG2014011523590001 |

foreach { 

$line = $_.Trim()

If ($line.Contains('CFTT82E')) {

    $str = $line.Split(' ')

    $TIDT = [ordered]@{

        IDT  = $_.SubString(101)

    }

    New-Object PsObject -Property $TIDT
    }
} | Out-String
```

I know that I ask a lot but, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you. Create an ArrayList for finding stored values then look at your file. Do something with IDT if it's not in the list, then add it to the list so it will be ignored on subsequent runs.

```
$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

while (1) {

    $content = get-content "C:\your\file.txt"

    foreach ($line in $content) {
        if ($line -match "CFTT82E.*IDT=(.+?)\b.*") {
            $idt = $matches[1]
            if(!$list.contains($idt) {
                #
                # Do whatever you need to do with $idt
                # 
                $list.add($idt)
            }
        }
    }
    sleep -Seconds(5*60)
}
```

Comment: Hey arco444,thanks for replying.My question is how to split the IDT value, insert it in a variable or an array and then apply the loop described above. then, once the command in the loop succeeded, on the next execution to exclude this IDT from my research so that it will not run the command again with the same IDT.I hope now it is clearer. thanks once again

Comment: You're the best. The script works great, but if my command could't work, that is to say, I have the second code CFTR12I code AND my IDT value, I have to re-run the command. So, once the command executed, I have to verify also the CFTR12I code associated to the IDT that I run in my command. Otherwise, the script is great man!! Thank you once again!!!